# In Rails 4, destroy link works in non-https, doesn't in https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm using the standard generator for deleting objects in Rails 4:

```
%td= link_to 'Destroy', archetype_choice, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

It works perfectly fine if you load it as an `http` link, but if you use `https`, it just goes to the `SHOW` route.

Comment: are you also loading Rails' Javascript helpers over HTTPS?

Comment: @sevenseacat You're totally correct, I'm not -- you can write that as the answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' destroy links work using custom Javascript helpers that will intercept the click, rewrite it, and then send it to the server.

For this to happen and for security reasons, the javascript file (likely `application.js`) must also be served over HTTPS.